# synchronous require so entire Node.js script isn't in callback

Tags: node.js, async-await, webassembly

When using WebAssembly, there is a callback for onRuntimeInitialized().  You basically can't do *anything* until it happens.

So if you have a library that is implemented in it, you have to say:

```
var mylib = require('mylib')
mylib.onRuntimeInitialized = function() {
    ...
    // Anything that wants to use *anything* from mylib
    // (doesn't matter if it's synchronous or asynchronous)
    ...
}
```

On the plus side, you're not making Node wait to do any initialization that might not rely on mylib...so other modules can be doing fetches or whatever they need.  On the negative side, it's pretty bad ergonomics--especially if everything you're doing depends on this library.

One possibility might seem to be to fold the initialization waiting into a promise, and then wait on it:

```
var mylib = require('mylib')
await mylib.Startup()
```

But people apparently [write about how much they don't like the idea of top-level AWAIT](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221).  And my opinion on it is fairly irrelevant either way, as it's not allowed.  :-/

So is there really no way to hold up code at the top level besides wrapping the whole app in a callback?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note with Node is that `require`s will return the same object, no matter what file that require is called in. Order does matter, but it will be the same object in all files.

So in your main `index.js` you could do something like

```
var myLib = require('mylib')
myLib.libby = myLib.initialize()
```

and then in another file, `doesStuff.js`, you can do:

```
const libby = require('mlib').libby
module.exports = function doStuff() {
  /* do stuff with initialized libby object */
}
```

Typically the way this works is that call in `doStuff.js` is not called until everything is initialized and say the web route is handled. So your server is running already and so `libby` will be initialized and ready to use once it's called.

If you have something that *absolutely cannot fail*, like the server will not run if DB connection is not successful or something, then waiting is appropriate, so yes, you'd need to wrap everything (at least the core of your actions) in a callback so your server knows when it's safe to start.

Comment: *"If you have something that absolutely cannot fail, like the server will not run if DB connection is not successful or something, then waiting is appropriate"*  WebAssembly `onRuntimeInitialized()` is basically that.  It's the platform itself loading.  :-/  I can't register any callbacks for anything else (e.g. an express `app.get()`) that calls anything at all from the webassembly, until this is ready, lest the callback happen beforehand.

Comment: Right. It sounds like what you suggest would work. While a top-level await or fully synchronous startup is not typical, if everything will break until something is initialized, then IMO it is ok to wait until that thing is ready, because you wouldn't have much of a program otherwise! :)